# very simple file version control

Tags: version-control

I'm looking for a way to do version control on a set of files, but not for project history, more of an extended undo. Basically I'm looking for a very simply version control with little overhead that will watch a directory for changes then save the differences so I can go back and view any file at any save. I don't want all the features of git or another version control like it. Also I don't want to have to commit changes, changes should be save as soon as a file is modified. Any suggestions?

I'm contently running into situations I write a block of code, save the file, rewrite the block of code, save the file, then realize I need it like it was at first but can't undo in my text editor for some reason.

Comment: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.webdav.autoversioning.html. But just using better editor will be better

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox has a very simple version control only for files. You can revert to any previous version and every time yo save changes and updates the file it creates a new version. You can work on Dropbox folder to do this automatically

Comment: I've used dropbox in the past, but have had some problems getting it to play well with linux. Plus I was hoping for a solution that didn't require internet access. Sound like the type of thing I'm looking for though.